# create-react-app missing file?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-native-app\build\index.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058  
npm ERR! syscall chmod  
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'C:\Users  \Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-native-app\build\index.js'  
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.  
npm ERR! enoent  

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:  
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs  \2018-06-26T16_24_58_412Z-debug.log
```

Trying to learn React Native but the starter won't work. What is it complaining about?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try npm cache clean --force
2. Restart your system.
3. Make sure your dir has a read and write permissions.

Still you didn't fix update node and npm

Comment: Tell me if you fixed out your problem.or i will find other solutions